# Typeset similar to that used in the Encyclopædia Britannica

Tags: typography

Can anyone tell me the name of a typeface that closely mimics (or is exactly representative of) the one used in the fifth edition of the *Encyclopædia Britannica, 5th Edition*? I have included a picture here for reference:

[image: Encyclopædia Britannica, 5th and 6th Editions.]

**Please note that the 5th edition appears in the *top* section of this image only.** The bottom section pictures the *6th edition,* which has a different typeset. I'm not necessarily looking for a typeset that includes the archaic ligatures such as the long s and the 'ct' patterns seen in the image; I only wish to know one that mimics the general style of the 5th edition's typeset (if one exists).

I apologize if the answer to this question is blatantly obvious.

Comment: What's an Encylopedia? `:)`

Comment: It's a Caslon font or one very similar. Adobe Caslon would be a good option, or Typotheque William if printing at small sizes.